# Azure Queue - Visibility Time-Out - Triggered WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-queues

I like to change the timespan a Q-message is invisible in the scenario where a webjob is triggered upon arrival of a message in the Queue.

I need this in the dev-stage while debugging. Sometimes an old Q-msg re-appears due to a bug but I already cleaned up the blob-storage-item the message was refering to. Hence WebJob crashes because it tries to get that not existing blob-object.

If I could set that the Q-messages are again visible after 1 min, that would be helpfull.

public partial class Functions
{
    public static void ProcessBulkFileQ(
        [QueueTrigger(AppConst.Q_BULKFILES)] JobInfo JobInfo,
        [Blob(AppConst.CONTAINER_BULKFILES + "/{BlobName}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream InputStream,
        [Blob(AppConst.CONTAINER_BULKFILES + "/{BlobName}")] CloudBlockBlob BlobToDelete
        )
    {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the latest v1.1.0 release of the SDK we've added the ability for you to add custom **QueueProcessor**s to control various aspects of message processing. You can see an example of what you're looking to do [here in our tests](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/test/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.EndToEndTests/AsyncChainEndToEndTests.cs#L408).

In that example, for failed messages, you can explicitly set the visibility to your own value based on the error details. You can register custom QueueProcessors by creating your own factory and setting it on **JobHostConfiguration.Queues.QueueProcessorFactory**.